# How to check if a web page is open or not?

Tags: javascript

I have a website where users message each other through another website. My problem is that everytime user click on message item this action opens a new tab.

Having a lot of conversations makes this quite annoying, especially when using on a smartphone.

Is there any way to check if the website for texting is open?

Comment: Look at ajax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using window.open() you can add the target parameter.

> A string, without whitespace, specifying the name of the browsing context the resource is being loaded into. If the name doesn't identify an existing context, a new context is created and given the specified name. The special target keywords, _self, _blank, _parent, and _top, can also be used.

**example**

```
window.open("https://www.mozilla.org/", "mozillaTab");
```

Comment: Great this is what i needed. Another problem is that when I use this for the second time the website will no longer get focus but simply reload. Is there any way to handle it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can add .focus(), which should work.
Example:
window.open("https://www.mozilla.org/", "mozillaTab").focus();

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Synapsis:

```
postMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer)
```

- `message` is the actual message you want to send
- `targetOrigin` specifies which domain is the target
- `transfer` is a sequence of transferrable objects that are transmitted with the message

So, what you really want is to have this conversation:

- Page1: are you there?
- Page2: yes

or

- Page1: are you there?
- ... (timeout)

I will call Page2 the page whose existence we wonder about and Page1 the page which wonders about Page2's existence.

First of all, you need a message handler at both Page1 and Page2. Synapsis:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080")
    return;

  //check event.data and see what happens
}, false);
```

On Page 2, your message handler will need to check whether the message asks about its existence and calls `postMessage('Yes, I am here', event.origin);` if so. Page1, on the other hand initiates the messaging by calling `postMessage('Are you there?', theurl);` (where you need to replace `theurl` with your value). Now, Page1 expects a message. If the message arrives, then Page2 exists. If not, then after a timeout you need to handle the nonexistence of Page2. So, you will have something like this at Page1:

```
var wasFound = false;
postMessage('Are you there', theurl);
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!wasFound) {
        //The page needs to be opened
    }
}, 500);
```

Naturally, you will need to set `wasFound` to true when you receive a message from Page2 and you will need to make sure that the message handler sees the same `wasFound` variable that your `timeout` checks for.